# Unable to set a breakpoint to debug an add-in project in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, add-in

I have followed the instructions on this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fb383x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on how to debug an add-in project and I've failed to do it. Upon selecting F5 Start debugging another Visual Studio opens but it will not break on my breakpoint no matter where I put one.

Any advice?

Comment: are you getting *breakpoint will not currently be hit* warning on the breakpoint signal?

Comment: I have never seen such a warning. It would appear on the breakpoint with a exclamation icon on it?

Comment: Yeah. If you go to the piece of code where the breakpoint is set, the red circle has a yellow warning sign and if you pass the mouse over it will have a message similar to that. Are you getting this?

Comment: No, I would've noticed something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem myself last week when I was moving an add-in from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010.  There is a known issue where you won't hit breakpoints if your add-in is built against a version of the .Net framework before 4.0.  For me, changing to 4.0 fixed this problem.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650694/vs-2010-sp1-breaks-add-in-debugging-targetting-net-framework-2-0-rather-than-net-framework-4-0#details

Another thing to try is running `devenv` from the command line with the parameter `/log vslog.xml` then exit.  Check the file `<ApplicationData>\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\vslog.xml`.  This might tell you that there's some other problem loading your add-in which means the dll isn't getting loaded.

Comment: You've nailed it. Thank you! Add-in was created way back in VS2005.